# How to read only a particular JSON node from MongoDb in SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to read a single JSON node from MongoDb via my Springboot project.

here is the sample JSON saved in Mongo:

```
    "a": {
            "b": {
                "c": {
                    "d": "value1",
                    "e": "value2"
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried:

```
   public String get() {
       BasicDBObject query = BasicDBObject.parse("{\"a.b.c.d\": \"value1\"}");
       FindIterable<Document> dumps = mongoOperations.getCollection("data").find(query);
       return dumps.first().toJson();
   }
```

response I got:

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5e8aa42602ef9f05bf35ff59"
        },
        "a": {
            "b": {
                "c": {
                    "d": "value1",
                    "e": "value2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but I only need the node a.b.c.d, I know I can do it in java after reading the whole JSON. But my intention is to read only the needed part.

Expected Output:

```
    {
       "a": {
            "b": {
                "c": {
                    "d": "value1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also please note that I'll be saving JSONs with random schema so no POJOs associated with it. It would be really helpful if somebody can guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the specified field only, using a *projection* with the `find` query. Tried with MongoDB Spring Data 2.2.6:

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "testDB");

Query qry = new Query();
qry.fields().include("a.b.c.d").exclude("_id");
List<Document> list = mongoOps.find(qry, Document.class, "collection");
list.forEach(doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```

The output:

```
{"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": "value1"}}}}
```